# Анимация в CSS3

Tags: css3, анимация

Всем привет. Есть код, перемещающий круг в заданную точку и обратно:

```
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  from {background: red; top: 50px; left: 50px;}
  to {background: yellow; top: 300px; left: 300px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes myfirst {
  from {background: red; top: 50px; left: 50px;}
  to {background: yellow; top: 300px; left: 300px;}
}
#ball {
border-radius: 100%;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
animation: myfirst 1s linear 0s 2 alternate;
-moz-animation: myfirst 1s linear 0s 2 alternate; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: myfirst 1s linear 0s 2 alternate; /* Safari и Chrome */
}
```

Проблема в том, что после того как анимация прекращается круг исчезает.. 
Подскажите где ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Круг не исчезает, просто стили, выставленные при анимации, заменяются начальными значениями.
Чтобы круг был виден после анимации, в стили круга добавьте:

```
background: red; top: 50px; left: 50px;
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/vEv4R/)

Comment: Спасибо. Можно ещё вопрос?))
Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы круг передвинулся в нужную точку и там остался. Делаю так:
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 2s linear 0s 1;
    -moz-animation: myfirst 2s linear 0s 1;
Но круг передвигается к заданным координатам и потом снова оказывается на прежних. Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Нужно указывать те css-свойства для #ball, которые отвечают за вид в конце анимации. то есть вместо "background: red; top: 50px; left: 50px;" нужно написать "background: yellow; top: 300px; left: 300px;".
http://jsfiddle.net/vEv4R/1/

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз)